# Turning data into list into dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to turn the data from this site (http://www.stat.duke.edu/~mw/data-sets/ts_data/exchange-rates) into a dictionary, where each # is a key and the number of occurrences of each # is the corresponding value.

Indeed I am a beginner, but I'm trying to understand and any pointers would help. I did not mean to ask for entire solution.

So far, I've tried this:

```
url = (urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/~bretscher/a20/f13/labs/exchange-rates-testing.txt'))
    data = url.read()
    new_data = data.split()
    for i in range(len(new_data)):
        counter = 0
        for num in data:
            if i == num:
                counter += 1
```

Ideally I'd use `counter` as the value in the dictionary and `new_data[i]` as the key. But when I do this, `counter` is returning zero. What could be causing this?

Comment: SO is not a place for people to do your homework. At least you should try out first.

Comment: Yes, somebody could help. Do you have another question?

Comment: @fyr0049 If learning to code involves asking others how to design a solution then I can't imagine how far new coders are going to get...

Comment: @Keikoku, if they get a job at a large company, maybe no one will notice for a while :)

Comment: OP, this is a blatant misuse of SO for assignment purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
import urllib
data = urllib.urlopen("http://www.stat.duke.edu/~mw/data-sets/ts_data/exchange-rates").read().split()
dict(Counter(data))
```